# Solving Optimization in Python via Scipy?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have to Solve an optimization problem(a complex one) with using python. I checked **scipy** tools although I can not adopt the still.

- Is there any tool similar to CPLEX for python ?( I Have 1 year experience in CPLEX)
- Have you got any advanced tutorial for SCIPY optimization tool for better learning it ?

I will be **glad** to take some answer to my questions.

Comment: This might better be asked on [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Scipy has [`linprog`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html), which works with continuous linear programs. If you have anything that is not an LP, you might want to look at, say, [Google's OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) or [SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org/). Most alternatives are commercial.

Comment: Thanks, I am checking your suggestions if I cant solve I will write again

Answer (score 0):

I suggest docplex (Cplex python api)

See

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer

Comment: So it is like extender way to solve an optimization, afterwards writing the optimization I will convert my code to offline application in this situation  "docplex" can still run offline ?